# Drawing on an image using emgu cv C++

Tags: emgucv

I am having difficulties figuring out how to draw a simple rectangle on an image using emgu cv. I'm using VS 2010 Express. I have a User Interface in which I am displaying a live video feed in a picture box on a panel which I have created using the .net framework. Now I would like to draw a clear rectangle in the middle of this feed, as that is where my code is focused on, and I need the user to see how to line up the camera and the object of interest so that it is in the rectangle. This is what I have so far in terms of drawing the rectangle on the frames from the camera

```
cv::Scalar red(0,0,255);
System::Drawing::Rectangle Rect = System::Drawing::Rectangle(120, 160, 150, 150);
frameColorDisplay->Draw(Rect, red, 2);
```

and this is the error that I'm receiving

```
BAOTFISInterface.cpp(1067): error C2664: 'void     Emgu::CV::Image<TColor,TDepth>::Draw(Emgu::CV::Seq<T> ^,Emgu::CV::Structure::Bgr,int)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'System::Drawing::Rectangle' to 'Emgu::CV::Seq<T> ^'
5>          with
5>          [
5>              TColor=Emgu::CV::Structure::Bgr,
5>              TDepth=unsigned char,
5>              T=System::Drawing::Point
5>          ]
5>          and
5>          [
5>              T=System::Drawing::Point
5>          ]
5>          No user-defined-conversion operator available, or
5>          No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or    

the operator cannot be called
```

I'm not sure why it's trying to convert from Rectangle to a Sequence? As far as I know, I'm calling the function properly according to the Emgu CV documentation. Does anyone have any insight into this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You need a TColor not scalar:

From the Docs
    C#

```
public virtual void Draw(
    Rectangle rect,
    TColor color,
    int thickness
)
```

Answer (score 0):

To find options for your TColor (as in GPPK's answer) look in EMGU.CV.Structure.  For instance, for a grayscale value you can pass

```
new Gray(0)
```

for black or

```
new Gray(255)
```

for white.  The expressions for HLS, HLV, etc. colors are only a little more complicated.